# CentOS 7 ESXi/VMware Hang on Boot

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, centos, esxi5.5

I installed CentoOS 7.0 1406 on a VMWare ESXi 5.5 hypervisor. I installed "Sever with GUI" and selected KDE. However on boot I get the following messages in under a second, before the process tops (waited 15 mins, multiple times):

```
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
```

With a flashing "_" but no ability to provide input.

The drive is encrypted. I do not know if CentOS's drive encryption would affect this (I haven't been given the ability to enter the phrase to decrypt the drive yet)

I tried reinstalling it from scratch, same error messages. I have a Windows 2012 server running on the hypervisor with no issues. I Googled around, and this doesn't appear to be an issue with CentOS in general, so I imagine it's some way that I configured my virtual machine, or installed the OS.

I'm running on 2 GB of RAM and 1 virtual core. I tried booting up with removing the vm's access to the network, and this changed nothing.

1. What is the issue?
2. What can I do to troubleshoot the current install/virtual machine?
3. How could I resetup the virtual machine, and reinstall the OS to avoid this issue in the future?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the GRUB boot menu, press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit the boot config and remove `rhgb`.

Edit:  You can disable it permanently by removing `rhgb` in `/etc/default/grub` and execute `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` to update your boot grub.cfg.

Comment: Can you explain why this works? I find it only happens when running disk encryption.

Comment: plymouth isnt working correctly, its supposed to give you a gui where you can enter a password instead of a blank screen. So by disabling rhgb (redhat graphical boot) you get an alternative way of entering your password.

Comment: hi, any idea what command that i should type in grub> prompt?
sorry i'm newbie to centos here
*i'm using centos 7

Answer (score 1):

At the grub prompt, hi 'e' to edit the parameters.  Remove rhgb quiet from the kernel parameters.  It's a known bug.

Answer (score 0):

So I tried doing a fresh install **without drive encryption** and it appears to be working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Download a newer version of the CentOS installation media and re-install. This problem seems to affect CentOS 7 systems from 2014. I experienced this problem installing a system from CentOS-7.0-1406-x86_64-Minimal.iso. I downloaded the latest ISO (which is CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1511.iso as of this writing) and the problem disappeared. The server was able to mount encrypted volumes on boot.